# Bokeh CustomJS Issue with Destructuring Instances

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, bokeh

So, I have been trying to create a select box in Bokeh with a CustomJS to filter data in a streamlit app.

Unfortunately I cannot attach the dataframe but the dataframe src2 is a data frame with columns stated below and src is a dataframe which is consisting of lists in each row/column item --> to be unpacked into src.

So I start with src in the proper format and then replace these values with lists from src2 indices. (Index getting found by `var x`).

The code below works in jupyter notebook but not in my streamlit app.

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(select=select,src=src,src2=src2), code='''
      const indices = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < src.get_length(); i++) {
        if (src.data['nme'][i] == 'L'){

            console.log(src.data['date_range_train'][i])
            console.log(i, src.data['i.l'][i], Number(select.value))
            if (src.data['i.l'][i] == Number(select.value)) {
              //indices.push(i)
              var x = i;
        }
        }else{
            console.log(i, src.data['i.lo'][i], Number(select.value))
            if (src.data['i.lo'][i] == Number(select.value)) {
              var x =i;
              //indices.push(i)
        }
      }}

      var date_range_train = src.data['date_range_train'][x];

      console.log(date_range_train, x)

      src2.data['mean'] = src.data['mean'][x];
      src2.data['10'] = src.data['10'][x];
      src2.data['90'] = src.data['90'][x];


      src2.change.emit()
    ''')
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

And I absolutely cannot figure out why...

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Presumably streamlit is using an older version of Bokeh and this code uses something too new for it. The browser JS console or debugger should be able to give some indication of what line this error is happening on. That's really the necessary piece of information.

Comment: I don’t see any line numbers. I see JS chunk 2 but not much other than that. I have another JS chunk which works properly earlier in the script.

Comment: Not possible to say much concrete without more info or complete code to run. The last three assignments look suspect. The value of `source.data["foo"]` should always be an array, but it looks like the RHS of those assignments are individual scalars, not arrays. If `src.data['mean']` starts out as a "list of arrays" (so that indexing it returns an array), then that assignment overwrites it the first time, and all subsequent times would be assigning a scalar (an error)

Comment: src2.data['mean'] etc. start out as a regular df - with a column (array) equalling the series to be plotted. Then I am overwriting this with an index of src which is a list of arrays - therefore an index returns and array of the same size as the original src2 array?

Comment: Thist is a JS callback, and there are no DataFrames in JavaScript. So the above description does not make sense as stated. In any case without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to focus and clarify the issue, all I can really suggest is adding more `console.log` statements until you find the value that is not what you expect.